# Hidden iCarousel Item reflection effect

Tags: ios, xcode, coverflow, icarousel

I got an app with iCarousel library. All works perfect. But i need cover flow without reflection. How should i dismiss it? Thnx.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

iCarousel doesn't include reflections - the reflections in the example app are just part of the background image.